# How can i redirect when person type in url browser?

Tags: django

I have two methods ,(register and confirm methods),when submit register,send message in mobile for verification,then person type and the code is correct ,i return this code and pass to response of jquery

```
  return JsonResponse({'code':1,'url': '/user/confirm'})
```

in jquery code with window.location() ,it will redirect into confirm page,
but i want to when person type this url and Enter ,he can not open this page(confirm page) and redirect into other page.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the `Accept` header sent by the browser, and send JSON only when requested, and a [redirect response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) otherwise.

You may need to add the Accept header to your jQuery call too.

```
def that_view(request):
    # ... do things ...
    if 'json' in request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT', ''):
        return JsonResponse(...)
    return redirect(...)
```

Comment: hi,but when i added  headers {Accept: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",} i can not see in confirm page,i want to use in confirm method,but ajax in register method

Comment: You'd obviously want to add `Accept: "application/json"`.

Comment: i have problem,ajax do not send headers to next page(from register to confirm page)

Comment: i want to access this header in confirm page,but i have that in register page,becuse url in ajax is for register page,